# CSS3 Gradient Woes

Tags: css, gradient

I've always relied on the excellent colorzilla gradient tool for creating my cross-browser friendly gradient CSS - but it's struggling on recreating an existing gradient which is working in some browsers already. I can't quite get the right combination of vendor prefixes and fallbacks to make it work reliably across the board currently.

The existing (working for FF / Chrome) CSS is:

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top , #00B9E6 0%, #00B9E6 38%, #003766 68%) repeat fixed 0 0 transparent;
```

Can anyone give some pointers on the best order/variations of this with vendor prefixes etc to allow it to work in all modern browsers?

Comment: Tools like http://prefixr.com/ are helpful in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this out, and it works in all *modern* browsers as you wanted.. however, if you want support across most browsers (including the old), I suggest a CSS3 polyfill.. current support for CSS gradient found **[here](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients)**.

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top , #00B9E6 0%, #00B9E6 38%, #003766 68%) repeat fixed 0 0 transparent;
background: -moz-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top , #00B9E6 0%, #00B9E6 38%, #003766 68%) repeat fixed 0 0 transparent;
background: -o-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top , #00B9E6 0%, #00B9E6 38%, #003766 68%) repeat fixed 0 0 transparent;
background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top , #00B9E6 0%, #00B9E6 38%, #003766 68%) repeat fixed 0 0 transparent;
```

You could also use **[less](http://lesscss.org/)** if you want to avoid the repetitive -moz, -o, -webkit abbreviations.

Comment: You're just blindly throwing in prefixes.  IE doesn't require prefixes at all.

Comment: @JoshC, this is always true because IE9 and below don't support CSS gradients at all, prefixed or not:)

Comment: @JoshC, my opinion is "yes". They were needed at some point for early beta releases of IE10, but I don't think that any significant number of people actually uses them:).